# AWS Lambda not connecting to my Redis server on EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, redis

I have created a Redis server on my EC2 instance on the default VPC and allowed inbound connection to it via my security group. I am able to connect to my redis via redis-cli on my local machine's terminal and also when I run my node js code locally.

My lambda and my EC2 instance are both on the same AWS region.

Within my lambda handler I want to connect to my redis and then use that single client across the entire invocation

**Lambda Handler**

```
import { APIGatewayProxyHandler } from "aws-lambda";
import serverlessExpress from "@vendia/serverless-express";
import ExpressApplication from "./express.app";
import MongoDbConnectionService from "./services/mongodb-connection-service";
import RedisService from "./services/redis-service";

let connection = false;

export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (
  event,
  context,
  callback
) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  if (!connection) {
    connection = await MongoDbConnectionService.connect();
  }

  // connect to redis server
  await RedisService.setDefaultRedisClient();

  let serverlessExpressInstance = null;

  const expressApp = new ExpressApplication();
  serverlessExpressInstance = serverlessExpress({ app: expressApp.app });

  return serverlessExpressInstance(event, context, callback);
};
```

**redis-service.ts**

```
import { RedisClientType, createClient } from 'redis';

export default class RedisService {
    private static _redisClient: RedisClientType;

    public static async setDefaultRedisClient() {
        console.log("---- inside setDefaultRedisClient");
        
        this._redisClient = createClient({
            url: `redis://${process.env.REDIS_HOST}:${process.env.REDIS_PORT}/0`,
            password: `${process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD}`
        });

        this._redisClient.on('connect', () => console.log('Redis Client Connected'));
        this._redisClient.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));
    }

    public static async getDefaultRedisClient(): Promise<RedisClientType> {
        if(!this._redisClient) {
            await this.setDefaultRedisClient();
        }

        return this._redisClient;
    }

}
```

When I make a test api call, it does reaches till the `console.log("---- inside setDefaultRedisClient");`  but then nothing happens after that. I do not get either the connect or error logs under it and the implementation meant to ready the data from redis return null.

Comment: Is your Lambda function configured to run in a VPC?

Comment: Ensure your Lambda has permissions to r/w Redis in its role.

Comment: @MarkB yes I have given access to the default VPC and its subnets + security groups

Comment: @cyberwombat so my Lambda already has access to the default VPC and subnet in which my EC2 instance is running what more r/w permissions do I need to give it? PS: I am creating the Lambda using serverless framework

Comment: I misread - didn't realize it was inside the EC2. Where is the `connect()` function for Redis called? I see a Mongo one only